# Using Firebase Authentication but need to improve security

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am a final year student and currently have an application that uses Firebase in order to process login requests. I have a sign-up activity and a login activity. Currently, I have one account registered on Firebase and use it with my testing. I have came to the part of my report that asks about the security aspects I have considered and the app that I have developed when accessed it will show all the data no matter who is logged in.

Is there any way that I can improve this or how secure is Firebase Authentication?

Comment: firebase authentication is as strong as you tell it to be. you have to edit the security rules to make it more secure. Check here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

Comment: The rules are for the database not authentication

Comment: @PeterHaddad he said: "the app that I have developed when accessed it will show all the data no matter who is logged in." Which  means he either isn't using firebase rules. Or he doesn't have custom logic on his App to only show areas for authenticated users. I was assuming the first scenario.

Comment: yeah @Dylan think Peter is correct. I guess what i'm getting at is, I dont have a way to differentiate the data that is shown depending on who is signed in. I am not storing any data using Firebase, only using the authentication login process

Comment: Thats up to you. You can tell if a user is authenticated or not.. You have to implement that part. Itll be as secure as you build it to be. Authentication only serves 2 purposes. 1.) To log in a user. 2.) To tell you if a user is logged in. You have to use #2 to determine what to show to your user.

Answer (score 2):

The Firebase authentication will enable you to let users login using either password, Google sign, Facebook, yahoo, Microsoft, etc..

All the details regarding a user are stored securely in the Firebase servers. In your case, you need to determine if the user is logged so he can see any data and you shouldn't show any data to the user unless he is authenticated.

The other solution is to use firebase database and create different parent nodes, example a node called `teachers` that will contain list of teachers, then you can add the teacher's name as an attribute under a class node and you will be able to retrieve all the classes that the teacher is teaching.

Thus, only retrieving data related to that specific user.